# How to save Xlsxwriter file in certain path?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Where does Xlsxwriter save the files you have created? Is it possibly to specify the path where I want the excel files to be saved?

My XlsxWriter script was in file /app/smth1/smth2/ and for some reason it saved the excel file to /app/. Shouldn't it have saved it in the same file where the script was? Or do I have to specify the path like this:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(' /app/smth1/smth2/Expenses01.xlsx')
```

What is the default file where the excel file is saved?

Comment: RTFM man. A 30-sec google got me [here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/tutorial01.html) where it says that `xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses01.xlsx')` takes the file name as an argument.

Comment: My script was in file /app/smth1/smth2/ and for some reason it saved the file to /app/. Shouldn't it have saved it in the same file where the script was? This is why I'm asking this question. Or should I have specified the path workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(' /app/smth1/smth2/Expenses01.xlsx') for the file to have been saved in this path?

Comment: This is an entirely different question - I advise you to fix your question accordingly. I suspect that you should specify the full path as the argument.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's how you can save the file to the current directory (where your script is running from):

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
```

Here's how you can specify a full path:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:/Users/Steven/Documents/demo.xlsx')
```

Here's how you can specify a relative path:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('app/smth1/smth2/Expenses01.xlsx')
```

Note that a starting "/" is not needed and may cause errors.

More examples can be found [here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_demo.html)