# Saving excel work book not working in python

Tags: python, export-to-excel

```
for sheet_name in book.sheet_names():   
    for index in range(len(tabs)):
        tab = tabs[index]
        if sheet_name == tab:       
            dump_file_name = dump_files[index]
            dump_file_name = file_prefix+dump_file_name
            sheet = book.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)

            new_book = Workbook()
            sheet1 = new_book.add_sheet("Sheet 1")          

            for row in range(sheet.nrows):
                values = []
                for col in range(sheet.ncols):

                    sheet1.write(row,col,sheet.cell(row,col).value)


            xlsx_file_name = dirname+"/"+dump_file_name+".xlsx"
            sheet1.title = xlsx_file_name           
            new_book.save(xlsx_file_name)
```

The file is creating and data is there, but if I open it in openoffice.org and click the save button it asks for new name. 
The file can not be read by PHP also. Again if I open and save it with new name then it works perfectly. I think we have to add something in the code so that it could be used by PHP.

Answer (score 1):

i did google and found the solution here
http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/getting_started.html
This is exactly what i wanted.
Creating and saving files to xlsx format.
Now its working perfectly.

**original source** 
[How to save Xlsxwriter file in certain path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904654/how-to-save-xlsxwriter-file-in-certain-path)

important link:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyExcelerate