# How to Get The Path of an Excel Workbook with Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

Pretty much, I have the following code, generating an Excel file.

```
import xlsxwriter
myName = 'hello.xlsx'
wbk = xlsxwriter.Workbook(myName)
```

The file `hello.xlsx` is generated in the same directory, where the Python file is. I can refer to the file path easily like this:

```
import os
print (os.getcwd()+"\\"+myName)
```

However, is there a way to refer to the path, only using only `wbk`? Something like `wbk.Path` from [vba](/questions/tagged/vba).

Comment: I don't think this is possible because wbk is a variable with no information about the path of the excel file

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904654/how-to-save-xlsxwriter-file-in-certain-path?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @JvdV - No. I am trying to get the path without referring it. Looking for a solution like `wbk.Path` from or something similar.

Comment: You can try `wbk.filename` (see [here](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/blob/b79f2b9ec2027bd1750c15c4612210dd3cff5be2/xlsxwriter/workbook.py#L66)), but as it's undocumented, there are no guarantees.

Comment: `wbk.filename` is a good way, but it only prints the filename, and I am looking for the whole path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, is there a way to refer to the path, only using only wbk

No.

The Workbook object only sees, and stores, the filename that is passed to it by the user. So if the user doesn't pass the path then the object can't store it.

I'd suggest using `os.getcwd()` like in your example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. [Here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44864839#44864839) it is proposed to "create a new class with additional `.Path` property. Then inherit defaults and expand with that." Isn't this a better approach than `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: I don't think that is a better approach since it is more, and in this case unnecessarily,  complicated.