# 'XlsxWriter' object has no attribute 'save'. Did you mean: '_save'?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to save data from a dataframe in excel file by using pandas. I was trying the following code.

```py
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
data = {'Name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Adam'], 'Age': [25, 30, 35], 'Gender': ['M', 'F', 'M']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Example: Adding a chart
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1.$B$2:$B$4'})
worksheet.insert_chart('D2', chart)
writer.save()
```

But I get the following error:

```
writer.save()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'XlsxWriter' object has no attribute 'save'. Did you mean: '_save'?
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: These might help: https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/190 https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/191 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904654/how-to-save-xlsxwriter-file-in-certain-path

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I didn't find the solution to my problem. The main problem is that the code works on my old pc, while on my new pc doesn't. I though that the problema could be different version of the python libraries, but I still don't manage to find the solution.

Answer (score 62):

The `save()` method has been deprecated and removed in Pandas. You should use `close()` instead.

With older versions of Pandas you would have gotten this warning:

> FutureWarning: save is not part of the public API, usage can give unexpected results and will be removed in a future version

With more recent versions you just need to use `close()` like this (I also fixed the syntax for the chart values):

```py
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

data = {
    "Name": ["John", "Jane", "Adam"],
    "Age": [25, 30, 35],
    "Gender": ["M", "F", "M"],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1")

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]

# Example: Adding a chart
chart = workbook.add_chart({"type": "line"})
chart.add_series({"values": "=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$4"})
worksheet.insert_chart("E2", chart)

writer.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use a context manager via `with` statement. As soon as you leave its indentation, the XlsxWriter handle will be closed and the file will be created.

```py
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Adam'], 
    'Age': [25, 30, 35], 
    'Gender': ['M', 'F', 'M']
})

with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", index=False)
    
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]
    
    # Example: Adding a chart
    chart = workbook.add_chart({"type": "line"})
    chart.add_series({"values": "=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4", "name": "=Sheet1!$B$1"})
    worksheet.insert_chart("D2", chart)
```

[image: result]